# How to transform one return type to another return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

```
MainController
 @GetMapping("/{id})
public ResponseEntity<Resresource> getId( @PathVariable("id") String id){
Resresource response = acservice.GtpResponse(id);//here it gives error as Required -> Resresource but provided Object. If i change from Object than How to transform Excel to Resresource
return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
}

Service.java
public Object GtpResponse(String id){
Optional<Acc> acc = accrepo.findById(id);
if(acc.isPresent())
return //fetches the details and returns Resresource
OPtional<Excel> response = Optional.ofNullable(getExcel(id));
if(response.isPresent()){
return the response
}

Resresource.java
private String id;
private List<DetailRes> details;

Excel.java
private String Excelfield;
private List<AllDetailsExcel> details;
```

I need to keep the return type as Resresource in controller but in service the Resresource and Excel is of the different return type. However, I have taken the return type as Object in the service class but I need to transform Excel to Resresource and than return Resresource as the return type. Kepping Object as the return type works but that is not the accepted one. I tried multiple times to transform Excel to  Resresource but didn't get any good way out.

Comment: You can cast to a ResResource, but make sure that it is actually a ResResource or else it will throw an exception. The better thing to do is to fix your function so that it doesn't return two types, Optional<Excel> and ResResource, there is something weird happening here.

Comment: Assuming there's no inheritance relationship between those two types, you're going to have to write some code to convert an object of one type to an object of the other.

Comment: I did' get any way even casting is not working

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please format your question better, it's so hard to figure out what's going on there.

Second, we need more information, but from what i can tell there is no relationship between `ResResource` and `Excel` and given this you can't use casting. As someone said in the comments, you need to write a custom mapper between the two, or have some sort of way of defining a generic object.

For example:

`Excel extends ResResource` but this is just an assumption

```
    Service.java
    public ResResource gtpResponse(String id){
      Optional<Acc> acc = accrepo.findById(id);
      if(acc.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getExcel(id)).orElseGet(null);
      }
    }
```